# Set up spyne to skip a field which is not present in SOAP request?

Tags: python, soap, spyne

I have a SQLALchemy model with such a column:

```
updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now(),
                        onupdate=func.now())
```

Which generates WSDL:

```
<xs:element name="updated_at" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
```

In the update request `updated_at` field is missing, and spyne maps its value to `None` causing this:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) null value in column "updated_at" violates not-null constraint
 'UPDATE subcsription SET updated_at=%(updated_at)s WHERE subcsription.id = %(subcsription_id)s' {'subcsription_id': 27, 'updated_at': None}
```

How can i set up spyne to skip the field at all when it is not passed in SOAP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface and your database schema don't need to match 1-to-1. You can define a separate object that doesn't have the `updated_at` member and use it as the input type in your service definition. E.g.

```
class SomeObject(TableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'

    id = UnsignedInteger64(pk=True)
    updated_at = DateTime(server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    some_data = Unicode

class SomeWriteObject(TableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'

    id = UnsignedInteger64(pk=True)
    some_data = Unicode

# or, you could do this:
class SomeWriteObject(TableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    _type_info = [ (k,v) for k,v in SomeObject._type_info.items()
                                                  if not k in ('updated_at',) ]
class SomeService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(SomeWriteObject, _returns=UnsignedInteger64)
    def add_some_object(ctx, obj):
        ctx.udc.session.add(obj)
        ctx.udc.session.commit()
        return obj.id
```

This way `updated_at` will be left out in the insert query which will leave it to the database to fill that field according to your instructions.

Comment: This means manually specifying fields and excluding some of them? Because right now fields are automatically extracted from a SQLALchemy model. I ended up monkey-patching spyne to not set field values of an incoming object if they were not passed in a SOAP request. This also solves a problem, when a spyne field is optional, but it was not passed in SOAP request, causing it to be overwritten with `None`.

Comment: This doesn't need to be done manually, see my edit. Also, could you share your monkey-patching code in some github gist? It could help others.